# Using Google Calendar API php without logging in

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I'm trying to access a Google Calendar without logging in like in [this tutorial](http://cornempire.net/2011/12/31/part-1-setting-up-google-calendar/).
I followed the tutorial, but it does not work for me. I managed to get my refresh token, but when I try to get an access token it only returns false.

I also tried to use the Google Client Api for php:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('online');
$client->setApplicationName('#######');
$client->setClientId('###############');
$client->setClientSecret('################');
$client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri);
$client->setDeveloperKey('###############'); 

$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);

$_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
$_SESSION['oa2_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
```

When I use this it says I'm using an unauthorized client.